# Calling a bash builtin function with a parameter within awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have this command which outputs 2 columns separated by `⎟`. First column is the number of occurrence, second is the IP address. And the whole thing is sorted by ascending # of occurrence.

`awk '{ips[$1]++} END {for (ip in ips) { printf "%5s %-1s %-3s\n", ips[ip], "⎟", ip}}' "${ACCESSLOG}" | sort -nk1`

19 ⎟ 76.20.221.34
19 ⎟ 76.9.214.2
22 ⎟ 105.152.107.118
26 ⎟ 24.185.179.32
26 ⎟ 42.117.198.229
26 ⎟ 83.216.242.69

etc.

Now i would like to add a third column in there. In the bash shell, if you do, for instance:

`host 72.80.99.43`

you'll get:

`43.99.80.72.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer pool-72-80-99-43.nycmny.fios.verizon.net.`

So for every IP appearing in the list, i want to show in the third column its associated host. And i want to do that from within awk. So calling `host` from awk and passing it the parameter `ip`. And ideally, skipping all the standard stuff and only showing the hostname like so: `nycmny.fios.verizon.net.`

So my final command would look like this:

`awk '{ips[$1]++} END {for (ip in ips) { printf "%5s %-1s %-3s %20s\n", ips[ip], "⎟", ip, system( "host " ip )}}' "${ACCESSLOG}" | sort -nk1`

Thanks

Comment: You didn't actually add a question. Is it "How do I get the output of a shell command in awk?"

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, that's what log resolvers are for, they are optimized for this exact task.  A log resolver is going to be a lot faster than running `host` for each IP, but it will still be slow (that's the nature of DNS).  Beware however that you'll put a lot of strain to your DNS server no matter how you do it, so it might be a good idea to talk to your sysadmin before doing this on regular basis.

Comment: Still, it is good opportunity to deepen knowledge of tools used daily on a server, like awk.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Also, could you give a little more details about those log resolvers you are talking about? Are they builtin functions or library based? Should i download them? Are they open source so that i may check the code out?

Comment: Google for "httpd log resolver".  Most of them are not specific to `httpd`, they can resolve logs as long as the each line in the file to process begins with an IP address (followed by a blank).  Apache comes with an utility named `logresolve`, that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use system() since you want to combine the shell command output with your awk output, you'd call the command as a string and read it's result into a variable with getline, e.g.:

```
awk '{ips[$1]++}
END {
    for (ip in ips) {
        cmd = "host " ip
        if ( (cmd | getline host) <= 0 ) {
            host = "N/A"
        }
        close(cmd)
        printf "%5s %-1s %-3s %20s\n", ips[ip], "⎟", ip, host
    }
}' "${ACCESSLOG}" | sort -nk1
```

I assume you can figure out how to use `*sub()` to get just the part of the `host` output you care about.

Comment: Whoa. It takes about 40 seconds to give back the results. I thought it was stalling... But it works.

Are we sure that the `host` command is only querying the IPs once they are uniqued out and not querying 92 times an IP that was logged 92 times?